# Upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and JupyterLab won't respect my config file

Tags: jupyter-lab

I've had jupyterlab running on this Ubuntu machine for over a year, never really had any issues with it.  I had created a configuration file that forced a password, specified cert and key files, listened on any interface (since it's not exposed anywhere but my LAN), possibly one or two other tweaks.  JL was also started at boot with systemd.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 today and suddenly, JL will not honor my configuration file.  It's listening on localhost only, no password protection, https doesn't respond, even simple port modifications don't get applied.

I disabled the systemd service and started troubleshooting manually; literally making no progress at all.  I backed up my config file and ran the command to create a new one.  With the new config file, all I changed was the port.  Started JL manually and it listens on the default port of 8888.  I launch JL with the --config=[full path] and it still completely ignores it.  I thought maybe it was a permissions issue, but the config file has the right owner and group (same as it's always been as far as I know) and it's 644 so I would assume all should be good there, not to mention, I created a whole new file.  I even went so far as to remove all jupyter packages via pip3 and reinstall, no joy.

So it seems to me the config file is being ignored no matter what I do.  When I manually run it, I really don't get much information, i.e. I'm not getting an error that says "failed to read configuration file, falling back to defaults" or anything like that.  These 2 warnings are all that comes up when I run it manually:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.4) or chardet (4.0.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
/home/buee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_server/transutils.py:13: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
  warnings.warn(warn_msg, FutureWarning)
```

But I'm pretty sure I caused this myself in the troubleshooting process.

Anyone have any ideas?  Am I looking at a bug or pebkac?

Comment: What version of JupyterLab are you running?

Comment: Assuming that your current version is 3.x, and you previous version was 2.x you need to migrate the configuration files to new locations, as there was a change to the underlying infrastructure, see: https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html

Comment: I am currently running 3.0.12.  Looks like the answer by @krassowski got it working for me.  I'm surprised I didn't come across this in my 4 hours of troubleshooting/Googling.

Comment: @krassowski if you want to submit that as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your current version is 3.x, and you previous version was 2.x you need to migrate the configuration files to new locations, as there was a change to the underlying infrastructure (which will help in maintenance and give you more benefits down the line in the future), mostly:

- renaming `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file to `jupyter_server_config.py`, and
- renaming `c.NotebookApp` traits to `c.ServerApp`;
- in addition, some traits may be deprecated or moved to more appropriate apps (e.g. LabApp/ServerApp etc); follow run-time messages in the terminal (after opening the app) to adjust your configuration as needed.

See [jupyter-server documentation](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html) for more details.