# Jupyter Lab opening in wrong path, different from Jupyter Notebook, both have same mapping in "jupyter_notebook_config.py."

Tags: path, jupyter, config, git-bash, jupyter-lab

I typically open Jupyter Lab from Git Bash, with command
`jupyter lab`

But today it suddenly opened in a different folder than usual
[wrong folder in Lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMeHP.png)
I checked opening Jupyter Notebook also from Git Bash and it opens in the usual folder.
[right, usual folder in Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiTdo.png)

I checked "jupyter_notebook_config.py." and they are both mapping to the same dir

`# c.LabApp.notebook_dir = ''`

`# c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''`

However, I found these lines for Lab but not for Notebook

`## The app directory to launch JupyterLab from.`

`#  Default: 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Anaconda3\\share\\jupyter\\lab'`

`# c.LabApp.app_dir = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Anaconda3\\share\\jupyter\\lab'`

Anyone might know why is jupyter lab opening in the wrong folder?
I checked these already

- [How to change the Jupyter start-up folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder)
- [How to navigate to a different directory in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755604/how-to-navigate-to-a-different-directory-in-jupyter-notebook)

Also, from Git Bash this opens
`$ jupyter notebook --notebook-dir 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\'`
But this doesn't open
`$ jupyter notebook --notebook-dir 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\MyWork'`

Jupyter Lab cannot see the MyWork folder, which is a GitHub master repo, could that be related?
[see side to side, File Explorer vs Jupyter Lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mqo2.png)

Comment: Are you using JupyterLab 3.0? If yes, it is no longer using  jupyter_notebook_config.py but jupyter_server_config.py instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66860252/6646912

Comment: installed Version is 2.2.6, is a company computer = no admin rights

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

1. Push to GitHub
2. Open GitBash and `cd` navigate to the parent folder of the desired folder (MyWork)
3. Launch `jupyter lab` from that parent folder